# How do I add another coding workspace in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html

I am trying to add an about.html to my website, but whenever I click the link nothing happens. I'm trying to connect to another workspace. I have already done js and CSS, but this about page's link isn't working. Here is my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="about.html" type="text/html" />
```

Comment: I guess you forget to upload you code please update your question.

Comment: Do you want to create a link that whenever you click on it, the page goes to the about.html file?

Comment: Yes, and the about.html is like a whole other site.

Comment: ``type`` is not needed you can remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're trying to reference the **about.html** is true and there's no matter about it, it might be because of the wrong address you gave.

1. If *about.html* is in the same folder the link you wrote is write. also `link="./about.html"` would be true.

   ```
   ++ main
        -- index.html
        -- about.html
        -- style.css
        -- script.js
   ```
2. If *about.html* is in a folder you must give the name like this `link="folder/about.html`, This must work if the structure of your folder is like this:

   ```
   ++ main
        -- index.html
        -- style.css
        -- script.js

        ++ folder
               -- about.html
   ```
3. If your *about.html* is in the previous folder of the main you should use `..` `link="../about.html"` to go back one step like this:

   ```
   about.html

   ++ main
          -- index.html
          -- style.css
          -- script.js
   ```

- and use `../../about.html` to go two steps backward.

This is all you need, if this doesn't work, you're referencing the wrong address.

Answer (score 2):

**Your code should be like this.**

`<a href="about.html">About</a>`

`<a href="index.html">Index</a>`

**Ping me if this is what you want.**

**Note:** Question is not understandable so this answer is kind of guess that he/she may be need this.

Answer (score 0):

first check wether you are trying to access a file like style or js or want to create a link. if you want to create a link then use anchor tag for the same e.g
 about us

and the it will work as link to access about page.

Comment: Please don't use comments as answers.